# Matplotlib fill_between() Multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, linechart, fill

I am plotting four lines which form an area in between them, an area I am trying to fill. However, I can't quite figure it out due to the limited amount of arguments I can use to define the area.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#global values

sigma_ct_inf = 0
sigma_ct_0 = 0
sigma_c_inf = 30
sigma_c_0 = 12
beta = 0.8

#values T 70
A = 359000
Wb = 40830202.33
Wt = 72079066.94
Mmin = 701.17
Mmax = 978.52


#Magnel Diagram
e = range(0, 1001)

disqualities = [1, 2, 3, 4] #'t70_top_0', 't70_top_inf', 't70_bot_0', 't70_bot_inf'

for i in disqualities:
    if i == 1:
        t70_top_0 = pd.DataFrame(e, columns = ['x'])
        t70_top_0['y'] = ((t70_top_0.x - (Wt/A))/((Mmin*10**6) + sigma_ct_0 * Wt))*10**6

    elif i == 2:
        t70_bot_0 = pd.DataFrame(e, columns = ['x'])
        t70_bot_0['y'] = ((t70_bot_0.x + (Wb/A))/((Mmin*10**6) + sigma_c_0 * Wb))*10**6

    elif i == 3:
        t70_top_inf = pd.DataFrame(e, columns = ['x'])
        t70_top_inf['y'] = (((t70_top_inf.x - (Wt/A))*beta)/((Mmax*10**6) - sigma_c_inf * Wt))*10**6

    elif i == 4:
        t70_bot_inf = pd.DataFrame(e, columns = ['x'])
        t70_bot_inf['y'] = (((t70_bot_inf.x + (Wb/A))*beta)/((Mmax*10**6) - sigma_ct_inf * Wb))*10**6


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Magnel Diagram, T-70')
line1 = ax.plot(t70_top_0['x'], t70_top_0['y'], lw = 0.5, label = 'Top, t = 0')
line1 = ax.plot(t70_bot_0['x'], t70_bot_0['y'], lw = 0.5,label = 'Bottom, t = 0')
line1 = ax.plot(t70_top_inf['x'], t70_top_inf['y'], lw = 0.5,label = 'Top, t = \u221E')
line1 = ax.plot(t70_bot_inf['x'], t70_bot_inf['y'], lw = 0.5,label = 'Bottom, t = \u221E')

plt.fill_between(t70_top_inf['x'], t70_top_inf['y'], t70_bot_inf['y'], where=t70_top_inf['y']<t70_bot_inf['y'], color = 'r', alpha = 0.4)

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.ylabel('1/P0 [1/MN]')
plt.xlabel('Eccentricity [mm]')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new top curve can be defined as the minimum between the two existing top curves. And a new bottom curve as the maximum between the existing bottom curves.

The code below is somewhat simplified, using one common x-axis ('e'). The naming is the same as from the question, where bottom and top seem to be switched.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#global values
sigma_ct_inf = 0
sigma_ct_0 = 0
sigma_c_inf = 30
sigma_c_0 = 12
beta = 0.8

#values T 70
A = 359000
Wb = 40830202.33
Wt = 72079066.94
Mmin = 701.17
Mmax = 978.52

#Magnel Diagram
e = np.arange(0, 1001)

t70_top_0 = pd.Series({'y': ((e - (Wt / A)) / ((Mmin * 10 ** 6) + sigma_ct_0 * Wt)) * 10 ** 6})
t70_bot_0 = pd.Series({'y': ((e + (Wb / A)) / ((Mmin * 10 ** 6) + sigma_c_0 * Wb)) * 10 ** 6})
t70_top_inf = pd.Series({'y': (((e - (Wt / A)) * beta) / ((Mmax * 10 ** 6) - sigma_c_inf * Wt)) * 10 ** 6})
t70_bot_inf = pd.Series({'y': (((e + (Wb / A)) * beta) / ((Mmax * 10 ** 6) - sigma_ct_inf * Wb)) * 10 ** 6})

bot = np.min([t70_bot_0['y'], t70_bot_inf['y']], axis=0)
top = np.max([t70_top_0['y'], t70_top_inf['y']], axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Magnel Diagram, T-70')
ax.plot(e, t70_top_0['y'], lw=0.5, label='Top, t = 0')
ax.plot(e, t70_bot_0['y'], lw=0.5, label='Bottom, t = 0')
ax.plot(e, t70_top_inf['y'], lw=0.5, label='Top, t = \u221E')
ax.plot(e, t70_bot_inf['y'], lw=0.5, label='Bottom, t = \u221E')

# ax.fill_between(e, t70_top_inf['y'], t70_bot_inf['y'], where=t70_top_inf['y'] < t70_bot_inf['y'], color='r', alpha=0.1)
# ax.fill_between(e, t70_top_0['y'], t70_bot_0['y'], where=t70_top_0['y'] < t70_bot_0['y'], color='b', alpha=0.1)
ax.fill_between(e, bot, top, where=top < bot, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.4)

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.ylabel('1/P0 [1/MN]')
plt.xlabel('Eccentricity [mm]')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]